# Button programmatically added disapear when turning landscape in android

Tags: android, button

I have delveloped an array of ImageButtons that disapear when i turn the phone to landscape and back. Why is this?

Comment: You have to add these buttons back to your layout after orientation change since they are not stored in the XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods.

There's some information about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Basically the view is being destroyed and recreated when you rotate the screen, so you need to save the relevant information in `onSaveInstanceState()` so that when your view is rebuilt in `onRestoreInstanceState()` the view returns to where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Because unless you override it, rotating the phone finishes the activity and restarts a new one.  The new one will not have the added button, unless it was added in onCreate.  Your possible solutions are:

1)Override the recreate functionality, by add android:configChanges="orientation|resize" to your manifest for the activity

or

2)In onSaveInstanceState create an object that has all the info you need to save for the app, including the fact you added this button.  In onRestoreInstanceState take this info and readd the button, if it needs to be

Unless you have separate layouts files for landscape and portrait, solution 1 is far easier and should probably be used.

Answer (score 0):

When the phone is orientation changes, the current activity is destroyed and recreated.

You should save the instance state and when the activity is re-created restore your previously saved instance state.

Check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html for more information.

Hope this helps